# Does a SOC 2 SSAE report not come with a "seal of approval" from a certified auditor?

Tags: audit, ccsp

I'm studying for the CCSP exam and I'm confused with a test prep question in my study materials.

The question reads:

> "Which kind of SSAE report comes with a seal of approval from a
>   certified auditor?"
>
> A. SOC 1
>   B. SOC 2
>   C. SOC 3
>   D. SOC 4

I chose **B. SOC 2** because I figured that as one of the most detailed reports on controls at a service organization, it would certainly need to have some record ("seal") of a reputable auditor performing the study.

The test prep material says I'm wrong though:

> C. SOC 2 deals with the CIA tria.  SOC 1 is for financial reporting. 
>   SOC 3 is only an attestation by the auditor.  There is no SOC 4

OK, fair enough.  I can understand how SOC 3 would be an appropriate answer but why not SOC 2 as well?  Is there no attestation on a SOC 2 report by the auditor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOC 2 report includes a description of the tests performed by the auditor and
the results of those tests and the auditor’s opinion of the effectiveness of the individual
controls and systems. SOC 3 does not contain test information and details on the controls in place, but just reports whether the systems meet the requirements of the criteria for the specific trust service.

SOC 3 is commonly used as a “seal of approval” and placed on service providers’ websites and marketing collateral.

The link below will give more detailed comparison between SOC 1 , SOC 2 and SOC 3 reports.

https://www.aicpa.org/INTERESTAREAS/FRC/ASSURANCEADVISORYSERVICES/DownloadableDocuments/Comparision-SOC-1-3.pdf